# PHP not returning variable to ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an ajax request and am having trouble returning the JSON response correctly for subsequent handling.

In the PHP code below,  $unameExists returns true or false, but when I send that back to the JS success routine, console.log(data.unameExists); returns as undefined. And thus, my if/else statement execute correctly.

HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $this->username;?>" class="middle" />
```

JS

```
$('#username').on('blur', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "?module=Iders&controller=index&action=check_user",
        data: { 'username' : $('#username').val() },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, unameExists) {
            console.log(data.unameExists);
            console.log(unameExists);
            if(data.unameExists === 'true') {
                alert('Username is NOT available!');
            }
            else {
                alert('Username is available!');
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            //error
        }
});
```

PHP

```
public function check_userAction() {
    $username = trim($_REQUEST['username']);
    $unameExists = Users_Model_Users::isExistUsername($username);
    echo $this->renderScript('json', unameExists);
}
```

Comment: That is not how the success callback works. The second argument is going to be the `textStatus` of the request, not some data you are passing from your php script. All data returned by your script is going to be in the first argument. And echoing multiple JSON strings is going to cause an error in parsing as that will create invalid JSON

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans. So, what do you suggest?    echo $this->renderScript('json.unameExists');  ?

Comment: Can you show the message that comes in console

Comment: @Shibon Message in console is simply: "Success"

Comment: echo json_encode($unameExists);
echo $this->renderScript('json', unameExists);

here is two echo use any one

Comment: That's not even how functions work. You can't have two echo in a function and expect them to display twice. It will only display the first echo it sees and stops from there.

Comment: @Shibon I tried your solutions and it still results in "success" message on console log but not the true or false response that I need to determine my if/else statement in the JS. Any additional ideas?

Comment: @hungrykoala I removed one of the echo's but I am still not getting my the true or false response in the JS to determine my if/else statement in the JS. Any additional suggestions? Tx.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the manual would help here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You are not using the callback arguments as expected by jQuery. The first success-callback argument is the complete data returned from the server. It is either a string or some kind of object, based on the `dataType`.

As you do not set the `dataType`, jQuery guesses what is returned and will probably resolve to a JSON blob directly.

Use the following `console.log()` statements to check the content of the `data`-argument.

```
success: function(data) {
    /* When your PHP script returns a variable that is encoded into JSON: */
    console.log(data.unameExists);

    /* In all other cases check the `data` arguemtn directly: */
    console.log(data);
},
```

Comment: Tx @feeela. I changed the console log as suggested, added dataType, and also modified the question for more clarity. The variable data.unameExists returns as undefined. Any other suggestions?  Tx!

Comment: Well, check your PHP too: `$this->renderScript('json', unameExists);` => `unameExists` is not a variable (missing the dollar sign) and also check what the method `renderScript` really does and how to output JSON in the framework used here.